# Redirect a USB Keyboard to Stdin

Tags: python, usb, keyboard

I am wanting to run a Python script that constantly loops for input on a keyboard (its actually and RFID HID). The script will be run on startup, but the Raspberry Pi will be headless.

How can I send the usb keyboards text from /dev/input/ to the stdin of the python script?

Alternatively I could read from /dev/hidraw etc. in the script. The trouble is they are encoded. Using input() in the python script is enough for me but obviously requires stdin.

Comment: Could I just run the script after boot, and the input() would be in focus? With no password to login etc.

Comment: *"How can I send the usb keyboards text from /dev/input/ to the stdin of the python script?"* -> It would make more sense to read whatever node(s) it is you want information from.

Comment: Could you explain please?

Comment: By analogy, there is a file `foo.txt` that I need information from in my program, so I ask "How can I redirect `foo.txt` to the stdin of my program?"  The answer is normally you don't.  Although they are not normal files in the sense of being stored on disk, the nodes in `/dev` are normal in the sense that they don't output anything unless something actively reads from them.   When you open one for reading, the kernel provides the data.  So, if you want information from a device node that permits reading, you need to read it.  They are not processes whose output you can redirect.

Comment: To qualify that a bit, you can redirect a file to stdin via the shell: `myproc < foo.txt`.  In this case what literally happens is the shell reads the file for you. You could try that with the `/dev` nodes, but if you are writing a program to deal with them, you might as well just open them, especially if this is to be a background process.